# Requirements for IIS server used for web sync, merge replicaiton

Tags: sql-server, replication

Short question: Can anyone tell me what the requirements (especially when it comes to SQL components) are for the web server used as web sync for merge replication?

Background:

I have a solution which uses merge replication to do one-way data sync with the client application of the solution.

The server uses SQL Server 2008, the client SQL Server 2008 Express and initiates the pull subscription using RMO. The request goes through Web Sync. All is fine when the IIS and the DB is on the same server - the problem occurs when the IIS is on a standalone web server.

From the error logs, it seems certain SQL components are required on the web server to make this work - but I haven't been able to find which ones. I've tried installing SQL Server 2008 Express on this server, with no luck.

So: Can anyone tell me what the requirements (especially when it comes to SQL components) are for the web server used as web sync for merge replication?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [How to: Configure IIS for Web Synchronization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152511.aspx), SQL Server connectivity components must be installed on the computer that is running IIS.  Also, If you use the *Configure Web Synchronization Wizard* (which is recommended), you'll also need to install SQL Server Management Studio on the computer that is running IIS.

Comment: I am running IIS 7, which isn't supported by the wizard :-( But I will try the connectivity components and see if that works...